# OrangeHRM - Change the default first day of week from Sunday to Saturday for Time Sheets

Tags: orangehrm

I am new to OrangeHRM and am trying to set up the Time module for our employees to begin entering time. The system seems to create time sheets with Sunday as the first day of the week, however we use a pay period which ends on Friday so our weeks start on Saturday. I do not see any options in the Admin or Time menus. Can this be changed so that the time sheets are from Saturday to Friday?

Answer (score 0):

In OrangeHRM Admin user have authority to set first day of week. 
Option to set first day of week will be present on **Time** menu item. But admin can update this option only once. Once admin updates this again he cannot update this option.